# Is a bounded, linear, nonnegative and symmetric operator with finite trace on a Hilbert space Hilbert-Schmidt?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let

- $U=(U,\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle)$ be a separable Hilbert space and $\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|$ be the norm induced by $\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle$
- $Q$ be a bounded, linear, nonnegative and symmetric operator on $U$ with finite trace

> I've read that we can conclude that $Q$ is Hilbert-Schmidt, but I'm quite sure that this is wrong.

By the [Hilbert-Schmidt theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_theorem), there is an orthonormal basis $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of $U$ with $$Qe_n=\lambda_ne_n\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\mathbb N\tag 1$$ for some $(\lambda_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq[0,\infty)$. Since $Q$ has finite trace, $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\lambda_n\stackrel{(1)}=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\langle Qe_n,e_n\rangle<\infty\tag 2\;,$$ but the square of the Hilbert-Schmidt norm of $Q$ is equal to $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\left\|Qe_n\right\|^2\stackrel{(1)}=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\lambda_n^2\tag 3\;.$$

> Maybe we can show that $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\lambda_n^2<\infty$, but I don't think so.

Am I missing something or does someone know a counter-example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is generally true that if $M := \sum |x_n|<\infty $, then $\sum |x_n|^2 <\infty $, simply because of $|x_n|\leq M $, so that $|x_n|^2\leq M |x_n|$.

Now apply this to $x_n =\lambda_n $.